# JavaScript tabs are not defined outside an envent listener?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to ping the `content_scripts` to check the current state, so when my add-on popup load, and outside of the `addEventListener("click", (e) => ...` I'm trying to evaluate current state with this:

```
    browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})
    .then(getState)
    .catch(reportError);

    function reportError(error) {
      console.error(`Could not process: ${error}`);
    }       

    function getState(){
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
          command: "getInterfaceState",
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.response == 1){
                console.log("returned 1");
            }else{
                console.log("returned 0");
            }
        });     
    }
```

For some reason it never gets to `sendMessage` and since content scripts cannot be loaded in `about:debugging` I have no idea how to debug this, what I know is that it never makes it to `onMessage` listener inside my content script:

```
    } else if (message.command === "getInterfaceState") {       
        if (document.getElementsById('chkState').style.visibility==''){
            return Promise.resolve({response: 1});
        }else {
            return Promise.resolve({response: 0});
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

found the bug, I forgot to pass `tabs` to my function, writing it like:

```
 function getState(tabs){
```

works fine and tabs collection is accessible.